# Multiply values with condition, then sum them in an array

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to multiply each balance with its current exchange rate, then sum them in the [SUM in EUR] cell.

The **C** column is actually one single day, it goes from *Jan 1st* to *Dec 24th* and each day holds the current balances, exchange rates, and should also contain the sum in EUR (or any currency).

[image]

I tried multiple SUMIFS, as in:
sum if currency equals for example EUR, then multiply by EUR exchange rate, then the same as well for all possible currencies, adding them all together in the process..

Comment: Maybe simply add (hidden) column which uses VLOOKUP() and converts custom currency to EUR, then calculate SUM() by it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this with a single formula:

**Structured References using Tables**

- `exchRates` Refers to the Exchange Rate table
- `acctVal` refers to the table showing the balances

  ```
  =SUM(INDEX(exchRates,N(IF(1,MATCH(acctVal[Currency],exchRates[Currency],0))),2)*acctVal[Balance])
  ```

Since the above is an array formula, you need to "confirm" it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar

*The `N(IF(1,...` construct is a method of obtaining multiple returns from the `INDEX` function*

A less obscure method of obtaining the total is to add a column to your `acctVal` table where you compute the value in Euros of each balance, and then sum that:

The formula for `EurVal` is

```
=[@Balance]*VLOOKUP([@Currency],exchRates,2,FALSE)
```

[image]